# Mesh Analysis - Why the thickness is uneven on sphere?

Tags: 3d-printing

Any reason why are colors of thickness distributed unevenly since it is sphere shape?
I would expect one color.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Y-scale factor is 0.189, perhaps this is skewing your expectations.

[image]